# addTextChangedListener() on EditText in android ActionBar

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have my edittext as an action item in my actionbar (ActionBarSherlock, actually). the layout is in its own xml, everything works fine, I can access the contents of the edittext and change with no trouble.

I would like to add a change listener on this edittext. After loading onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and filling the menu I create my

```
EditText search=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar); // its name in a frame layout
```

and then

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
    }
});
```

I keep getting null pointer exceptions on this edittext. Problem is probably something blindingly obvious, but it makes me great deal of trouble..

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The action bar is not within the content view so calls to `findViewById` will always return `null`.

Instead, you need to call `menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item).getActionView()` to get a reference to the action view. Using that view you can call `findViewById` to get a reference to the `EditText` (or if the `EditText` is the root view then you already have the reference).

Comment: Jake, you really are an exceptional person! Best support I could have wished for;-). Of course, I needed to do this:

    View ref1=menu.findItem(R.id.input).getActionView();
    EditText search=(EditText) ref1.findViewById(R.id.searchbar);

and everything works fine.

Big thaks and kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts, neither guaranteed -

Have you checked that:

```
EditText search=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
```

returns non-null? If it returns null:

- Is the SetContentView (on the right file!!) before the line?
- Is there a problem in your xml somewhere ... or it may just need a "clean" and rebuild.

Or, have you accidentally done something to search between the two (eg. redeclared it)?